# How to suppress "Availability does not match previous declaration" warning

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-privateapi, suppress-warnings

I have to use some private functions, like:

```
SCDynamicStoreRef
SCDynamicStoreCreate            (
                    CFAllocatorRef          allocator,
                    CFStringRef         name,
                    SCDynamicStoreCallBack      callout,
                    SCDynamicStoreContext       *context
                    )               __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_1,__IPHONE_NA);
```

By default they are not allowed for iphone, so I've changed declaration of them in my .m file. But now it shows "Availability does not match previous declaration" warning. How to suppress this warning?

[image]

Comment: make it match to previous declaration?

Comment: @BryanChen In order to use private api I have to change availability of these functions (by default they are not allowed for iphone)

Comment: You actually *can* change the original SDK headers, to replace `__IPHONE_NA` with `__IPHONE_2_0`.  That should fix this problem.  Of course, if you do that, you might not get the warning on other projects, where you are building for the app store.

Comment: @Nate, yes I can. Also we can copy & paste default framework into project folder, but we need to copy it 2 times (for iphone & simulator architectures) and then change headers. But I think my solution above is more accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the usual disclaimer that using private APIs might cause your app to be rejected: 
You can suppress the warning with

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wavailability"
…
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

It might also cause crashes or other failures if that function is present in the iOS 
frameworks, but with different parameters.

Comment: The application will not be deployed to appstore. Thanks a lot for solution!